# In Javascript, how to convert a int value to a certain bytes and then combine with a string?

Tags: javascript, sockets

When using `write` method of net.Socket in Node.js, the method only accepts a string value.

Now I have a socket message of the rule:4 bytes of message length + message body. Eg, message='You are right', then length = 17.

I don't know how to form this message. Currently I use the following code, but when the message length > 128, the receive socket parse error.

```
function sendMessage(data) {
    var length = data.length + 4;
    var lenArray = new Uint8Array(4);

    lenArray[0] = length >>> 24;
    lenArray[1] = length >>> 16;
    lenArray[2] = length >>> 8;
    lenArray[3] = length;

    var arrayBuffer =  new Uint8Array(length);
    arrayBuffer.set(lenArray);

    var dataArray = str2ab(data);
    arrayBuffer.set(dataArray, 16);

    var dataSend = ab2str(arrayBuffer);
    client.write(dataSend);
}

function str2ab(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);

    for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bufView;
}

function ab2str(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Buffer Class that Node.js provides can solve this problem.

```
function sendBuffer(data) {
var length = Buffer.byteLength(data)+32;
var headBuf = new Buffer(4);
headBuf.writeUInt32BE(length);
var bodyBuf = new Buffer(length);
headBuf.copy(bodyBuf,0,0,headBuf.length);
bodyBuf.write(data, headBuf.length+12);
console.log(bodyBuf);
client.write(bodyBuf);}
```